# C# Using Delegates and Events in Database Classes - Winforms

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I created a Winforms project that has a few classes that make calls to the database.

As an example, one of these classes is called OwnerDB and it includes a method to insert a new Owner into an Owner table in the database.

I want to use a delegate and event to call the methods to update ComboBoxes or DataGridViews on other forms when an Owner is inserted.

Can you let me know if this is written correctly or if I should be using another method to accomplish this?

```
  class OwnerDB
{
    public delegate void AddOwnerToList();

    public static event AddOwnerToList AddOwner;

  public static void InsertIndividualOwner(TaxInfo taxInfo, OwnerAddress address, OwnerEmailAddress emailAddress, IndividualOwner owner)
    {
       using (connection)

using (SqlCommand insertCompanyOwner = new SqlCommand("spCompanyOwnerTransaction", connection))
{
 // Removed parameters to shorten code
            insertIndividualOwner.ExecuteNonQuery();
            AddOwner?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the constructor of my one of my forms I have the code below

```
  public frmOwnerManager()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OwnerDB.AddOwner += LoadOwners;
}
```

Comment: Where is `insertIndividualOwner` and `connection` defined (in the removed code?)? If `AddOwner` is an event, you should call it with `AddOwner?.Invoke()` instead.

Comment: That's in my database class and called from my form frmNewOwner 
    OwnerDB.InsertIndividualOwner(newTaxInfo, address, email, newOwner);

Comment: No, I'm talking about the DBCommand that you call inside the method, not the method itself. Typically if you "own" the connection and the command, you would put them inside `using` statements. Its also considered bad design to tightly couple your class to the UI (showing the message box in the catch).

Comment: Sorry it is defined in the method              SqlCommand insertIndividualOwner = new SqlCommand("spIndividualOwnerTransaction", connection);
            insertIndividualOwner.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                                                                             I can switch that to a using statement and I'll remove the message box from the catch statement. Am I correctly subscribing to the event on the other form?